# Merging two dataset with different lengths is throwing an Error in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to merge two `datasets/datatable` with different lengths but i am constantly getting the below error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(y, xkey, nomatch = ifelse(all.x, NA, 0), allow.cartesian = allow.cartesian) 

: 
  retFirst must be integer vector the same length as nrow(i)
```

I am not able to understand what the error message means. Can someone help?
i am using the below code to merge:

```
merge(x=Red,y=Error,by=c("loopN","TYPE"),all.x=TRUE)

datatable data:
```

```html
DATA TABLE RED

    TIME        TYPE loopN diff
11/26/2014 0:45 28808 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:00 28808 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:15 28808 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:30 28808 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:15 189379 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:30 189379 141126 0
11/26/2014 2:15 189379 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:00 239188 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:15 239188 141126 0
11/26/2014 1:30 239188 141126 0
11/26/2014 13:30 239188 141126 0


DATA TABLE ERROR

loopN TYPE V1
141126 28808 -2.932
141126 28808 -2.932
141126 28808 -2.932
141126 28808 -2.932
141126 189379 1.061
141126 189379 -1.182
141126 189379 4.771
141126 239188 -0.163
141126 239188 -1.573
141126 239188 -1.981
141126 239188 -1.981
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What Avinash means is: it would be useful if you could give us some example data.tables to work with ;).

Comment: Added the data table sample data for your reference

Comment: @Leo thats an error.corrected the error..

Comment: @Kaushal, do you mind using dput(Your_Data_Table_Here) to provide a sample of your data?  This is the best way (that I know of) to make your example reproducible.

Comment: @Leo let me twist the question then since i datatable is huge,10 lakhs records.So i think twisting the question will work. "How do i merge these two data table to one based on TYPE and loopN"

Comment: @Kaushal have you tried wrapping your data table as a dataframe?  Perhaps use as.data.frame() or as.data.frame.matrix() as a wrapper for Red and Error. I have not been able to reproduce the error with the information given thus far.

Comment: @Leo yes i have already tried but i keep getting the same error. i cant identify whats wrong with the merge statement

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing to do seems really odd. Your data.table `RED` has 4 records with `TYPE=28808` and `loopN=141126`. Similarly, your data.table `ERROR` also has 4 records with that combination of `TYPE` and `loopN`. So the merge (join) will produce **16** records. If your whole 1MM records data.table is like that, then the result will be huge. If this is really what you want, this will do it.

```
RED   <- structure(list(TIME = c("11/26/2014 0:45", "11/26/2014 1:00", "11/26/2014 1:15", "11/26/2014 1:30", "11/26/2014 1:15", "11/26/2014 1:30", "11/26/2014 2:15", "11/26/2014 1:00", "11/26/2014 1:15", "11/26/2014 1:30", "11/26/2014 13:30"), TYPE = c(28808L, 28808L, 28808L, 28808L, 189379L, 189379L, 189379L, 239188L, 239188L, 239188L, 239188L), loopN = c(141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L), diff = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("TIME", "TYPE", "loopN", "diff"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
ERROR <- structure(list(loopN = c(141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L, 141126L), TYPE = c(28808L, 28808L, 28808L, 28808L, 189379L, 189379L, 189379L, 239188L, 239188L, 239188L, 239188L), V1 = c(-2.932, -2.932, -2.932, -2.932, 1.061, -1.182, 4.771, -0.163, -1.573, -1.981, -1.981)), .Names = c("loopN", "TYPE", "V1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 11L))

# you start here...
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(ERROR),loopN,TYPE)
setkey(setDT(RED),loopN,TYPE)
result <- ERROR[RED, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Comment: I didn't get you point on "result"...Also i dont need 16 records. It should be 4 records where LoopN and TYPE from both RED and ERROR datatable should match. It's more like left outer join of sql with RED and ERROR.

Comment: Suppose `RED` had just the first 4 records, same for `ERROR`. Then both tables would have all records with exactly the same `TYPE` and `loopN`. Which record from `RED` would you match to which record from `ERROR`? Any join (left, right, cartesian), would match **each** record in `RED` to **each** record in `ERROR`, so, 16 matches and 16 rows in the result.